# Differentiate tag for two models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table called Tags (which are tags defined by me), and these Tags can be applied to two models: `Page and Server`

These are the associations:

```
page has_and_belongs_to_many tags
server has_and_belongs_to_many tags
```

So, a user can tag a Page and a Server using the pre defined tags.

However, some of those Tags might just be applied to Server, so whenever I want to show the list of Tags that can be applied to a Page, I want to avoid showing the ones that are just for the Server.

The way I have thought on solving this is adding two column that would say:

```
is_for_page, is_for_server
```

I want to avoid having two tables, one for tags for servers and one for tags for pages, because most of them will just be the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the following columns on the Tag model:

```
add_column :tags, :server_exclusive, :boolean
add_column :tags, :page_exclusive, :boolean
```

Then you can filter these tags based on these two columns:

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :for_pages, -> { where('page_exclusive = :true OR (page_exclusive = :false AND server_exclusive = :false)', false: false, true: true) }
  scope :for_servers, -> { where('server_exclusive = :true OR (page_exclusive = :false AND server_exclusive = :false)', false: false, true: true) }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask what is the advantage of doing ``server_exclusive`` instead of doing ``is_for_server``?

Comment: @HommerSmith I felt like 'server_exclusive' was more explicit, since a Tag which is only meant for servers, it this tag should not have 'is_for_server' (or another name) value as true. So `exclusive_` was pretty explicit to me. It does not bring any advantage really, it is really up to you to choose the name of the columns

Answer (score 0):

You can add one column "tag_type" instead of 2 columns and have a string like "Page", "Server", "All" or something like that and then you can easily filter by that type like

```
Tag.where(tag_type: "Page")
```

If you are on Rails 4.1 you can also use enums http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html